# SOLR - Update one field in a document using postman json query

Tags: json, api, solr, postman

I'm experimenting with SOLR and need to update one field in a document using json in postman, I've looked at documentation and posts but I haven't been able to get it to work, which seems weird for such a common operation.

I have the following document:

```
{
    "id":"556c630c-125c-4b52-8fa5-c26daf187782",
    "started":false,
    "cancelled":false,
    "complete":false
}
```

I've tried the following in postman:

```
--url:8983/solr/task-core/update/json/docs?commit=true
--json:
{
        "id":"556c630c-125c-4b52-8fa5-c26daf187782",
        "started":true,
}
```

But that overwrites the entire document.

I've read somewhere that you can use "set", but I couldn't get any combination to work, I'm using SOLR 7.7.1 if that helps.

Comment: You're submitting content to the `/update/json/docs` handler - try submitting it with the command `{started: {set: true}}` as described below to the `/update` endpoint instead.

Answer (score 0):

option to it partial update of the documents as below

```
{
 "id": "123",
 "author" : "Solr Updates"
}
```

Lets add an author field to the document the field value would be a json object with `"set"` attribute and the field value

```
$ curl http://localhost:8983/solr/update -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '
[
 {"id"       : "123",
  "author"   : {"set":"Robert Wark"}
 }
]'
```

Your new document will look like as below after you query

```
$ curl http://localhost:8983/solr/get?id=123
```

The updates document is :

```
{
 "doc" : {
    "id"    : "123",
    "author": "Robert Wark"
 }
}
```

Please refer the documentation :

[Partial Update](http://yonik.com/solr/atomic-updates/)

[Solr Documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/updating-parts-of-documents.html)

Comment: I tried: {
        "id":"556c630c-125c-4b52-8fa5-c26daf187782",
        "started": {"set": true}
} but got the error "msg":"undefined field: \"started.set\""

Comment: Please check your schema file. If it is missing the field named started, please add it.